# d3 histogram and barchart data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently creating a barchart that gets data from a d3 histogram.

I create the histogram like this:

```
var binningThresholds = d3.range(getMinValue(rows, 'Model year'), getMaxValue(rows, 'Model year') + 2)

var histogram = d3.layout.histogram()
    .value(getModelYear)
    .bins(binningThresholds)
    (rows);
```

I get rows from a csv input. I do a lot of stuff with the input already, so that works fine.

The histogram now is an array of an array of objects.

When I now want to use this `histogram` and add a bar to a chart for every index in the array, no error shows up and d3 does not append any `g`, `rect` or `text` tags to the DOM.

```
var histogramBars = histogramSvg.selectAll('g')
    .data(histogram)
    .enter()
    .append('g');

histogramBars.append('rect');

histogramBars.append('text')
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.length;
    })
```

I really don't know why, does anyone see a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.selectAll('g').data...`, my guess is that there's other `g` elements in your visualization and you are selecting things you don't mean to.  Instead do something like:

```
var histogramBars = histogramSvg.selectAll('.myUniqueClass')
  .data(histogram)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'myUniqueClass');
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it.

Comment: @Mark, it works the same even if you drop the `.attr('class', 'myUniqueClass')`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, it will for the initial `enter` selection.  If he needs to handle the update or exit case though, it'll be necessary.

Comment: That's true... but the class doesn't need to be the same! He can give it another name...